# BITCOIN: get bitcoin transactions list by time using RPC on my node

Tags: bitcoin-core, json-rpc, bitcoin-core-development

I want to get the transaction list of a bitcoin node i have. I need to know:

1. How do i get the transaction list filtered by time (1h, 2h,...) using RPC, I have been searching on [bitcoin developer: RPC API reference](https://developer.bitcoin.org/reference/rpc/index.html)  but i can't find a method that allows me to get the transaction list by time, there's only `transactionlist` method by quantity (number of transactions i want to).
2. How do i get a notification when a new transaction has been made, i've known already `walletnotify` where i specify a restAPI I created **(my/custom/route)** using curl from my node, and I recieve the txId anytime the node receive some change. The thing is, I need to store/queue those notifications whenever the restAPI i created got disconnected, if that service comes back/is restored the node needs to send those notifictions to my API.

Comment: You could get transactions by block, which is more official than "time".